# Apple Search API supportedDevices key

Tags: ios, json, app-store

Does the supportedDevices key always return "all" for iphone apps? I'm only interested in iphone apps, and not ipad apps, so I want to know what value to look for in supportedDevices to ensure it's an iphone app.

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Apple's documentation of the API is pretty limited. What are the possible values for the supportedDevices key?

Is there ever a case where an app is available for iphone but not for ipad?

EDIT:

I just noticed this example, https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=492861440

How would I go about determining that this app is valid on iPhone? would i use the key "kind", "features", or would I traverse through "supportedDevices"? I need a bullet proof way to ensure it's an iPhone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[All iPhone apps will run on iPad](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2010/01/all-iphone-apps-will-work-on-the-ipad), while iPad apps won't run on the iPhone unless they have appropriately sized XIB / storyboard /resources.

Looking at that example you pointed to, I can see "supportedDevices" comes back as:

```
"supportedDevices":["iPad2Wifi", "iPadWifi", "iPad23G", "iPad3G"]
```

(not sure why it doesn't say "iPad4")

And what's important here is that it doesn't say "all" or "iPhone", so if you don't see those two keywords in the JSON result, you should be safe in assuming it's iPad only.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=363714043
This app only runs on ipad, as you can see under supportedDevices, but it's kind is "software", not "ipadSoftware"

So I don't think I can use just the software to figure out if it's on iphone